# Export array with props input in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm currently creating a React app, and in it I want to be able to reference an array of values in any file I import the array. However, I want the array to be filled with values that are passed from another file via props. How can I do this? My array will always have the same number of values. Currently, my App.js file is structured something like this:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Array from './Array'

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Array valOne="7" valTwo="10" valThree="2" valFour="19"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Essentially, I want to be able to call `<Array />` with the four props in App.js, which would then set the values of that array `listData` to be those four numbers, which I could then call in other files as `import listData from './listData'` and reference each value as `listData[1]`, etc.

Comment: Is **Array** a component? If yes, please add snippet of the same. Is **listData** local state of any component? If yes, please mention the same.

Comment: Array is a component where I initialize a list of items, and their values are stored in a variable that is created in listData. I want to be able to reference listData from ./listData using props from Array.js or App.js, if that helps. @VinaySharma

Comment: It's quite confusing. First of all what exactly do you mean by **referencing listData**. And what's **listData**? It is just a file or a component?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small repl here: https://repl.it/talk/share/Stackoverflow-65599500/113403

If your are not getting access, look at the image link in the bottom.

What you are trying does acctually not make sense.
You need to pack your array values into something that can be showed in html.
My repl showcases that.

Array is an javascript object and not a react object. React is just a wrapper around html.

I did show case that with that simple function called: ArrayView

But have a look at the repl and see if it makes sense

[image of the code on repl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGrZt.png)